# I have a problem with loading the context in my Spring boot application, which I think comes from the wrong integration of the Firestore database

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project to implement in Spring Boot in which I have to integrate Firestore.

Firebase.config:

```
package spring.framework._2fa_application.config;


import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.repository.config.EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories(basePackages = "spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP")
public class FirebaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public void firebaseApp() {
        try{
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./ConnectionString.json");

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

            Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Firebase Admin SDK: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

CodeRepository:

```
package spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP;

import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.FirestoreReactiveRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public interface CodeRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<CodeData> {
}
```

CodeGeneratorServiceImpl:

```
package spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.FirestoreTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class CodeGeneratorServiceImpl implements CodeGeneratorService {

    private final CodeRepository codeRepository;
    private final CodeMapper codeMapper;

    private final int[] DIGITS_POWER = {1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000};

    private Mono<byte[]> hmacFunction(AlgorithmHash algorithm, byte[] keyValue, byte[] text)
    {
        return Mono.defer(() -> {
            try{
                Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm.toString());
                SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "RAW");
                hmac.init(macKey);
                return Mono.just(hmac.doFinal(text));
            }
            catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException exp){
                return Mono.error(exp); 
            }
        });
    }


    private Mono<byte[]> hexStr2Bytes(String hex){

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
           
            byte[] bArray = new BigInteger("10" + hex, 16).toByteArray();
            byte[] ret = new byte[bArray.length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
                ret[i] = bArray[i + 1];
            return ret;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<String> generateCode(String keyHex, final String time) {

        return codeRepository.findAll()
                .map(codeMapper::codeDataToCodeDataDto)
                .flatMap(codeDataDTO -> {
                    String algorithm = codeDataDTO.getAlgorithm();
                    int numberOfDigitsCode = codeDataDTO.getNrDigits();

                    return Mono.defer(() -> {
                        String modifierTime = time;
                        while (modifierTime.length() < 16) {
                            modifierTime = "0" + modifierTime;
                        }

                        return hexStr2Bytes(modifierTime)
                                .flatMap(timeText -> hexStr2Bytes(keyHex)
                                        .flatMap(key -> hmacFunction(AlgorithmHash.valueOf(algorithm), key, timeText)
                                                .map(hash -> {
                                                    

                                                    int offset = hash[hash.length - 1] & 0xF;
                                                    int binary =
                                                            ((hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
                                                                    ((hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) |
                                                                    ((hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) |
                                                                    (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

                                                    int otp = binary % DIGITS_POWER[numberOfDigitsCode];

                                                    String result = Integer.toString(otp);
                                                    while (result.length() < numberOfDigitsCode) {
                                                        result = "0" + result;
                                                    }

                                                    return result;
                                                })
                                                .onErrorMap(error -> new Exception(error.getMessage()))
                                        )
                                );
                    });
                });
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to solve it:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP.CodeGeneratorServiceImpl required a bean named 'firestoreTemplate' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'firestoreTemplate' in your configuration.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@7d0d91a1 testClass = spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP.CodeGeneratorServiceImplTest, locations = [], classes = [spring.framework._2fa_application.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@742ff096, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@79e4c792, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5b218417, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@1a75e76a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@4a003cbe, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@bdc2461f], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'codeGeneratorServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Licenta-Practic-2FA_2FA_application\target\classes\spring\framework_2fa_application\totp\codeOTP\CodeGeneratorServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'codeRepository' defined in spring.framework._2fa_application.totp.codeOTP.CodeRepository defined in @EnableReactiveFirestoreRepositories declared on FirebaseConfig: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'firestoreTemplate' while setting bean property 'firestoreTemplate'

I tried to inject a Firetemplate type variable in CodeGeneratorServiceImpl but it does not find the appropriate bean for it.

I tried to inject a Firestoretemplate variable into CodeGeneratorServiceImpl but it doesn't work, initially I had the problem that it couldn't find my path to the access keys, but I solved it by introducing the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable into the environment variables